# Writing to HBase table using version 0.98.0-hadoop2

Tags: java, mapreduce, hbase

I am attempting to write to an HBase table in Java using HBase version 0.98.0-hadoop2.  In the previous version I was using (0.94.x-hadoop1), Put implemented the Writable interface, and could be used in the reducer to write to an hbase table in the following manner:

```
Put row = new Put(Bytes.toBytes(unique_row_identifier));
put.add(family_bytes, qualifier_bytes, value_bytes);
... // other put.adds to the same row
context.write(null, put);\n
```

When using the upgraded jar (version 0.98.0-hadoop2), an error occurs at all lines with context.write(null, row) with the message "Incompatible types: Put cannot be converted to Writable."  In doing a little research, the Put object implemented Writable in version 0.94.0, but no longer implements this interface in 0.98.0.

Are there any other ways to write to an hbase table from a reducer?  Should this version of hbase be used?

Any suggestions are welcome.

Thanks

Comment: correct that was the case, I believe the problem was solved by changing some deeper dependency issues.  Thank you

Comment: I think you should add/update an answer with the dependencies for everyone's use.

Comment: My solution to this issue is as follows: Use Hadoop version 2.2.0.  For instance hadoop-common, hadoop-client, hadoop-mapreduce-client-app, etc. should all be version 2.2.0.  Use HBase version 0.98.3-hadoop2.  Just these changes ended up eliminating the issue I had above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you use TableOutputFormat as job outputformat? In 0.94.x, TableOutputFormat is extends OutputFormat. In 0.98, TableOutputFormat is extends OutputFormat. So context.write(null, put); should compile well in 0.98 because Put is extends Mutation. Make sure you hbase dependence is right.

Comment: I believe that dependency issues were the problem.  Thanks for the response